# Check current language in XML

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

The website has multiple store views.
By default, the form is shown in the footer.
I need to place it under the header, but only for one store view.

Is there any way to move it there via XML?

Comment: can you describe your requirement in details.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya question is updated, is everything clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should name your layout handle like this:

```
STORE_$code.xml
```

And move the block to header in this layout update.

If my notes are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new child theme, edit the xml in the child theme. Then associate the new created theme to the storeview you need.